# Ant JUnit results not being outputted

Tags: ant, junit

I am running an Ant task which runs junit tests.  I want the results of the tests to be outputted to XML.  I do:

```
<target name="test" depends="clean,compile">
    <junit showoutput="yes" fork="true">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        <batchtest  todir="${test.results.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${tests.dir}">
                <include name="**/*TestSuite.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

But nothing is outputted. What are my doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the formatter's type to `xml`.

```
<formatter type="xml" usefile="false" />
```

Remove the `usefile` attribute if you want to write the output to a file.

```
<formatter type="xml" />
```